# How to generate a frequency table in R with with cumulative frequency and relative frequency

Tags: r, histogram, frequency, cumulative-frequency

I'm new with R. I need to generate a simple Frequency Table (as in books) with cumulative frequency and relative frequency.

So I want to generate from some simple data like

```
> x
[1] 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 16 16 16 16 16 18 18 18 10 12 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 17 16 16 16 16 16 18 18 18 10
[36] 12 15 19 20 22 20 19 19 19
```

a table like:

```
            frequency  cumulative   relative
(9.99,11.7]    2            2       0.04545455
(11.7,13.4]    2            4       0.04545455
(13.4,15.1]    1            5       0.02272727
(15.1,16.9]   10           15       0.22727273
(16.9,18.6]   22           37       0.50000000
(18.6,20.3]    6           43       0.13636364
(20.3,22]      1           44       0.02272727
```

I know it should be simple, but I don't know how.

I got some results using this code:

```
factorx <- factor(cut(x, breaks=nclass.Sturges(x)))
as.matrix(table(factorx))
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You're close! There are a few functions that will make this easy for you, namely `cumsum()` and `prop.table()`. Here's how I'd probably put this together. I make some random data, but the point is the same:

```
#Fake data
x <- sample(10:20, 44, TRUE)
#Your code
factorx <- factor(cut(x, breaks=nclass.Sturges(x)))
#Tabulate and turn into data.frame
xout <- as.data.frame(table(factorx))
#Add cumFreq and proportions
xout <- transform(xout, cumFreq = cumsum(Freq), relative = prop.table(Freq))
#-----
      factorx Freq cumFreq   relative
1 (9.99,11.4]   11      11 0.25000000
2 (11.4,12.9]    3      14 0.06818182
3 (12.9,14.3]   11      25 0.25000000
4 (14.3,15.7]    2      27 0.04545455
5 (15.7,17.1]    6      33 0.13636364
6 (17.1,18.6]    3      36 0.06818182
7   (18.6,20]    8      44 0.18181818
```

Comment: also should give a plug to `??` function which allows for fuzzy searching, i.e `??"cumulative sum"` would lead you in the right direction.

Comment: It worked nice, it was confusing me that the display of the data is done as a **data frame** (instead of a table). The `??` is realy good but I'm not native English speaker so is difficult to search help.

Comment: @El_Hoy - compare the output of `str(as.data.frame(table(sample(1:10, 100, TRUE))))` and `str(table(sample(1:10, 100, TRUE)))` to see the difference in the output. Formatting as a data.frame just makes it easier to add the cumsum and proportions. Good luck! Lots of good info here on SO and plenty of people who like answering questions.  Cheers!

Answer (score 25):

The base functions `table`, `cumsum` and `prop.table` should get you there:

```
 cbind( Freq=table(x), Cumul=cumsum(table(x)), relative=prop.table(table(x)))
   Freq Cumul   relative
10    2     2 0.04545455
12    2     4 0.04545455
15    1     5 0.02272727
16   10    15 0.22727273
17   16    31 0.36363636
18    6    37 0.13636364
19    4    41 0.09090909
20    2    43 0.04545455
22    1    44 0.02272727
```

With cbind and naming of the columns to your liking this should be pretty easy for you in the future. The output from the table function is a matrix, so this result is also a matrix. If this were being done on something big it would be more efficient todo this:

```
tbl <- table(x)
cbind( Freq=tbl, Cumul=cumsum(tbl), relative=prop.table(tbl))
```

Answer (score 14):

If you are looking for something pre-packaged, consider the `freq()` function from the `descr` package.

```
library(descr)
x = c(sample(10:20, 44, TRUE))
freq(x, plot = FALSE)
```

Or to get cumulative percents, use the `ordered()` function

```
freq(ordered(x), plot = FALSE)
```

To add a "cumulative frequencies" column:

```
tab = as.data.frame(freq(ordered(x), plot = FALSE))
CumFreq = cumsum(tab[-dim(tab)[1],]$Frequency)
tab$CumFreq = c(CumFreq, NA)
tab
```

If your data has missing values, a valid percent column is added to the table.

```
x = c(sample(10:20, 44, TRUE), NA, NA)
freq(ordered(x), plot = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another possibility:

```
 library(SciencesPo)
    x = c(sample(10:20, 50, TRUE))
    freq(x)
```

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion is to check the *agricolae* package... check it out:

```
library(agricolae)

weight<-c( 68, 53, 69.5, 55, 71, 63, 76.5, 65.5, 69, 75, 76, 57, 70.5,
+ 71.5, 56, 81.5, 69, 59, 67.5, 61, 68, 59.5, 56.5, 73,
+ 61, 72.5, 71.5, 59.5, 74.5, 63)

h1<- graph.freq(weight,col="yellow",frequency=1,las=2,xlab="h1")

print(summary(h1),row.names=FALSE)
```