# Creating a percentage table

Tags: r

I've created a table based of counts based on two columns in my data frame. I used:

```
data.frame(table(df$State,df$Subset)[,])
```

Is there a way I can turn these counts into percentages for each specific State?

```
             S1       S2        S3       S4    S5     S6     S7
NY          195     1296       974     5528  3597    505    282
NJ          172      733       763     3253  3088    315    166
CA           48      552      1087     2073  1212   1149    203
```

So rather than counts, it each would be a percentage of each specific state. All NY would add up to 100% across, same with NJ, CA, etc..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate a frequency table in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11148868/how-to-generate-a-frequency-table-in-r)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if the comment `?prop.table` is enough. `prop.table` by default will only give you the cell-proportions, and what is being requested are row proportions.

```
tbl <
structure(c(195L, 172L, 48L, 1296L, 733L, 552L, 974L, 763L, 1087L, 
5528L, 3253L, 2073L, 3597L, 3088L, 1212L, 505L, 315L, 1149L, 
282L, 166L, 203L), .Dim = c(3L, 7L), .Dimnames = list(c("NY", 
"NJ", "CA"), c("S1", "S2", "S3", "S4", "S5", "S6", "S7")), class = "table")
```

Compare these two values:

```
> prop.table(tbl)
            S1          S2          S3          S4          S5          S6
NY 0.007171491 0.047662830 0.035820676 0.203302563 0.132286418 0.018572322
NJ 0.006325622 0.026957449 0.028060755 0.119635173 0.113566989 0.011584716
CA 0.001765290 0.020300835 0.039976463 0.076238461 0.044573572 0.042256629
            S7
NY 0.010371079
NJ 0.006104961
CA 0.007465706
> prop.table(tbl, margin=1)
            S1          S2          S3          S4          S5          S6
NY 0.015755029 0.104710350 0.078694352 0.446634887 0.290619698 0.040801487
NJ 0.020259128 0.086336867 0.089870436 0.383156655 0.363722026 0.037102473
CA 0.007590133 0.087286528 0.171884883 0.327798861 0.191650854 0.181688805
            S7
NY 0.022784196
NJ 0.019552415
CA 0.032099937
```

Only the second one is the basis for a "percentage estimate (which does require multiplication by 100):

```
> 100*prop.table(tbl, margin=1)
           S1         S2         S3         S4         S5         S6         S7
NY  1.5755029 10.4710350  7.8694352 44.6634887 29.0619698  4.0801487  2.2784196
NJ  2.0259128  8.6336867  8.9870436 38.3156655 36.3722026  3.7102473  1.9552415
CA  0.7590133  8.7286528 17.1884883 32.7798861 19.1650854 18.1688805  3.2099937
```

I think the more useful result would `round` that set of values to one decimal place.

Comment: Was trying to figure out how to use margin, and that helped a lot. Thanks

Comment: @rawr: I done't really understand your whinge. You get row proportions for margin = 1.  `margin.table` is for the marginal sum, not the row proportions. It's essentially `rowSums(tbl)`

Comment: perhaps it is your senility, but my complaints were about the obscure  documentation, not whatever you are currently prattling about

Comment: @rawr: Well, it you mean that fact that they define it with `sweep(x, margin, margin.table(x, margin), "/")`, and I have never thought that `sweep` was clearly defined, then maybe I agree with you. I'd rather hoped my senility was noticeable until 10 years from now.